# Scaling Android Widget

Tags: android, widget, scale

I have a widget with 2 oval buttons (defined in a XML file). At the moment, I've hard coded the width and height of the button to 180dp, but this poses problems when making the widget smaller.

Is there anyway I can set the width and height of the button to scale as the widget size is changed?

Comment: You can specify the minimum widget size using minResizeWidth and minResizeHeight. Also I would suggest you to go through, http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#design

Comment: I've got that specified. I'm talking about components in the widget. When the widget is made smaller, the button's still stay the same size and destroys the layout. I wan't the buttons to scale down/up if the widget is resized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Resizable widgets are preferred feature for collection widgets
>   such as those based on **ListView** or **GridView**. [App Widget Design Guideline](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html)

So for your purpose it's better to use different layout if your widget gets resized. On Android 4.1 and above you may use `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()` method to load different layout when your widget is resized. See these answers for more information:

1. [How to use onAppWidgetOptionsChanged() in a widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14062945/1693859)
2. [define widget's behaviour/layout for resize and orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14546306/1693859)